# Anyone who encountered this error while building the SensorKinect from source?

Tags: sensor, arm

Anyone who encountered this error while building the SensorKinect from source? The source was downloaded from https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect. The guide that I'm following was this: http://mewgen.com/Ge107_files/20120919%20Setting%20up%20Rasberry%20pi%20for%20the%20Xtion%20and%20kinect.htm

I have successfully build and installed both OpenNI and Sensor.

[image]

Comment: Yes I did. Did you find a fix? I get this error on both x86-64 and Arm targets.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the unstable version of OpenNI (from [here](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect)), see note in README.txt in SensorKinect:

```
***** Important notice: *****
You must use this kinect mod version with the unstable OpenNI release which is available at:
```

So, install unstable version of OpenNI:

```
git clone https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI.git -b unstable
```

Then follow the steps in the link you provided or at [here](http://gremsi.blogspot.com/2013/04/installing-openni-sensorkinect-and.html).